# Como usar preg_match() para pegar um link dentro de um código Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-match

Olá, estou fazendo um `file_get_contents()` no PHP e obtendo um JS, nesse javascript tem um código onde contem:

```
$("#download-botao").attr("href", "link.com");
```

Estou querendo pegar esse link.com no meu PHP, estou tentando através de `preg_match()`, com o seguinte código:

```
preg_match('/$("#download-botao").attr("href", "(.*?)");/', $url, $final);
```

porem não está funcionando, está retornando empty, quem puder ajudar, ficaria agradecido!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode verificar em: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oLJ

```
\$\("#download-botao"\)\.attr\("href", "(.*)"\);


array(2
0   =>  $("#download-botao").attr("href", "link.com");
1   =>  link.com
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de colocar toda a string na Regex, você pode colocar apenas a parte que interessa pegando o grupo 1, que é o que está entre o último par de aspas:

```
<?php
$url = '$("#download-botao").attr("href","link.com");';
preg_match('/,\s?"(.+?)"\);/', $url, $final);
echo $final[1]; // link.com
?>
```

**[Teste no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/JdZ41Y)**

Explicação da Regex:

```
,          tem uma vírgula antes
\s?        tem um espaço ou não após a vírgula e antes das aspas
"(.+?)"    qualquer coisa entre as aspas
\);        tem parênteses e um ponto e vírgula após a segunda aspas,
           onde o parênteses deve ser escapado com a barra invertida \
```